# Can I right-click music folder and select play under GNOME?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, mp3, media-player, context-menu

On Windows it's possible to right click on a folder of MP3s and (when it works) click on play to have the default media player queue up the contents in track order.

Does anyone know a way I can do the same thing on GNOME in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a nautilus plugin that does this.](http://seemanta.net/myblog/?p=634)

Instructions:

```
sudo aptitude install python-nautilus
wget http://seemanta.net/code/Nautilus_plugin/add-to-rhythmbox_V02.py \
  -P ~/.nautilus/python-extensions
killall nautilus
# Navigate to your music folder again, right click, add to play queue
```

Comment: the `nautilus -q` doesn't seem to work to restart nautilus.  i finally got it restarted by (1) `ps -ef | grep nautilus`, (2) `kill -HUP xxxx` (where xxxx is the PID found), and (3) `dbus-launch nautilus foo` where foo is the options to nautilus from step (1).  logging out of Gnome and back in should also do it.

Comment: @qq: Thanks, edited. Nautilus should launch again when a folder is selected from the places menu.

Comment: Thanks, works great! (Strangely the first time I tried it the tracks were out of order, but I haven't been able to recreate that.)

Answer (score 1):

Just install nautilus-actions and you can do a lot of things, including playing a folder in rhythmbox, banshee, and the like.